# Who can I marry?

Tags: story-of-seasons

I don't want to waste my time giving presents to people who won't marry me.

Who are the eligible bachelors/bachelorettes in town?

Comment: Yay for efficient buttering up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The marriage candidates have flowers next to their names when you speak to them

[candidates can also be found here](http://fogu.com/sos1/villagers/marriage/)

Bachelorettes for Male characters: Agate, Angela, Elise, Iris, Licorice, and Lillie

Bachelors for Female characters: Fritz, Kamil, Klaus, Mistel, Nadi, and Raeger

Comment: Wait a second, Mistel is a guy? WHAT?

Comment: haha, Yeah Mistel is Iris's brother.